# Break Batch file if line fails

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Here is the batch code;

```
echo off
echo ZD Install is currently loading the setup
echo Please wait...
start "" /w "\\products\setup.exe"
start "" /w "\\SP1\update.exe"
start "" /w "\\SP2\update.exe"
```

How do I make it so that if setup.exe is closed or fails that it wont run SP1 and SP2 and also give off a message saying it failed?

Comment: Possibly `errorlevel`?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@rem @set prompt=$G

@echo ZD Install is currently loading the setup
@echo Please wait...
@call "\\products\setup.exe"
@if %ERRORLEVERL% @goto :ProductsSetupFailed
@call "\\SP1\update.exe"
@if %ERRORLEVERL% @goto :SP1UpdateFailed
@call "\\SP2\update.exe"
@if %ERRORLEVERL% @goto :SP2Failed
@exit /b 0

:ProductsSetupFailed
@call :ShowError "Product setup" %ERRORLEVEL%
@exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:SP1UpdateFailed
@call :ShowError "SP1 setup" %ERRORLEVEL%
@exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:SP2UpdateFailed
@call :ShowError "SP2 setup" %ERRORLEVEL%
@exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:ShowError
@echo %~1 failed: %2
@exit /b %2
```